# How to create a geospatial pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, geospatial

I am trying to create an **interactive pdf** document with ->

1) A map with layers.
2) The layers could be turned on or off with the help of checkboxes.
3) The geospatial data will be retrived from database using java.
4) PDF will be created through java using that data.

Can someone suggest me some API or java library which can be used for the same. Also any example will help alot.

Answer (score 0):

For maps,  http://openlayers.org/ or http://leafletjs.com/ 
For database postgres 9.x with postgis (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html)
You can use jts-topology-suite library(written in java), or the classes under postgis distribution(postgis.jar), for mapping or reading geometries to/from java objects

For read `PGgeometry.geomFromString(the_geometry.toString())`

For write
`BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter();
 bw.writeHexed(PGgeometry.geomFromString("SRID=4326;" + the_geometry))`

The pdf must include the maps?

Comment: Yes, It must include the maps along with layers. Plotted lat/lon or any geometry.

Comment: Openlayers 3  have print map function

Answer (score -1):

I think when it comes to interactive Geopdf, there could be at least two paths to do this:

1) ArcMap + Acrobat pro, use ArcMap to export to pdf, and use Acrobat pro to set up the interactive part of the geopdf, in your case is the layer toggle plugin

2) I would assume someone would bring up Terrago anyway as commercial solution to this. https://www.terragotech.com/

I believe there could be some other solutions outside, but i personally have not use any of those.